# Passing arguments through __local memory in OpenCL

Tags: memory, opencl

I am confused about the the __local memory in OpenCL here.
I read some spec saying that the data flow has to be from Host to 
__Global, and then __Local. 
But I also see some kernel function like this:

```
__kernel void foo(__local float * a)
```

I was wondering how the data was transferred directly into the __local 
memory in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: So what would be passed to this argument? If you create a buffer on the host side, and then use `clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, length * sizeof(cl_float), NULL);` to pass the argument. What would be passed to the kernel? A NULL pointer?

Comment: @EvanzzzZ No, that would allocate `length*sizeof(cl_float4)` bytes of local memory for each work-group, and pass that pointer (with uninitialised data) to the kernel. You are not creating a buffer on the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to fill local buffer on the host side. Therefore you have to follow the flow host -> __global -> __local.

Local buffer can be either created on the host side and then it is passed as a kernel parameter or on gpu side inside the kernel.
Creating local buffer on the host side gives the advantage to decide about its size before the kernel is run which can be important if the local buffer size needs to be different each time the kernel is run.

Comment: If you create a local buffer on the host side and passed it as kernel argument, did you pass the data from host to local memory?

Comment: No. If you want to have host data in local buffer first you need to pass it from host in a global buffer and then on gpu copy it from global into local buffer.

Comment: The manual for clSetKernelArg says: If the argument is declared with the __local qualifier, the arg_value entry must be NULL.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html

Comment: So, the `__local` argument can only have its size (and not its content) specified by the host prior to invoking the kernel. Is this the *only* way to "allocate" local memory?

Comment: @StevenLu, the other way is to define the local variable/buffer inside the kernel with defined size.

Answer (score 2):

Local memory is not visible to anything but a single work-group, and may be allocated as the work-group is dispatched by hardware on many architectures. Hardware that can mix multiple work-groups from different kernels on each CU will allow the scheduling component to chunk up the local memory for each of the groups being issued. It doesn't exist before the group is launched, and does not exist after the group terminates. The size of this region is what you pass in as other answers have pointed out.

The result of this is that the only way on many architectures for filling local memory from the host would be for kernel code to be inserted by the compiler that would copy data in from global memory. Given that as the basis, it isn't any worse in terms of performance for the programmer to do it manually, and gives more control over exactly what happens. You do not end up in a situation where the compiler always generates copy code and ends up copying more than was really necessary because the API didn't make it clear what memory was copy-in and what was not.

In summary, you cannot fill local memory in any automated way. In practice you will rarely want to, because doing it manually gives you the opportunity to only put the result of a first stage into local, removing extra copy operations, or to transform the data on the way in to local, allowing padding or data transposition to remove bank conflicts and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I found it very helpful. Could you close the loop on the question, though, and comment as to whether this means that almost always there is no need to ever define or use `__local` kernel arguments?

Answer (score 0):

As @doqtor said, the size of local memory on kernel parameter can be specified by `clSetKernelArg` calls.

Fortunately, OpenCL 1.2+ support VLA(variable length array), local memory kernel parameter is not required any more.