# CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE when setting buffer arguments

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm writing an OpenCL program, and have found I'm reading a buffer out as all zeroes.   Diving into the Intel SDK tracing, I've found that I get a CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE when SETTING the buffer arguments.  (Setting scalar arguments does not produce an error)

I'm using the OpenCL C++ Bindings (cl.hpp).

Since my code is long I've replicated the problem with a test program.

```
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices.front());

cl::Buffer resultsBuf(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_short) * 2048);
cl::Buffer inputBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 2048, input.data());

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(inputBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 2048, input.data());

// Execution of the following two lines produces CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE for both.
err = kernel.setArg(0, resultsBuf);
err = kernel.setArg(1, inputBuf);

// Execution of the following line produces CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
err = queue.enqueueTask(kernel);

vector<cl_short> result(2048);
err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(resultsBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_short) * 2048, result.data());
```

and the Kernel code:

```
__kernel void myKernel(
    __local short* resultsBuf,
    __local uchar* inputBuf
) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i) {
       resultsBuf[i] = -3; 
    }
}
```

`input` is a `vector<cl_uchar>(2048)` filled with some test data, it isn't used for anything yet.  All I'm expecting from this test case is to read back a buffer filled with the value -3.

I've compared my code with other samples I've found online, and nothing jumps out at me as odd, I've tried various little adjustments (like changing the mem flags) and I can't seem to improve the situation.

Is there something I've overlooked about buffers?

(curiously my test program does fill `result` with a few junk bytes?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass data there and back between host and GPU you have to use global memory. That seems to be done OK on the host side but in your kernel you use `__local` memory address specifier which as the name suggest is to be used locally within the kernel.
Fixed kernel to use `__global`:

```
__kernel void myKernel(
    __global short* resultsBuf,
    __global uchar* inputBuf
) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i) {
       resultsBuf[i] = -3; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I honestly thought I had a choice about this.

Comment: You know if I set the kernel args to __private I get the error: "pointer arguments to kernel functions must reside in '__global', '__constant' or '__local' address space".  That seems to imply it might be possible to use __local ?

Comment: It seems that for inputBuf I can make it __constant without issue.  I guess there are different cases.  There is more about __local here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249801/passing-arguments-through-local-memory-in-opencl