# OpenCL CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error with images

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, kernel, opencl

I'm trying to make an opencl application for a university assignment. The assignment essentially asks us to do the following: first we need to calculate an intensity histogram from an image. Then we make a cumulative frequency histogram. That histogram is then normalized and finally used as a LUT to map the original intensities onto an output image. I'm currently attempting to make an initial version which I will show below.

C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Utils.h"
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

void print_help() {
    std::cerr << "Application usage:" << std::endl;

    std::cerr << "  -p : select platform " << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "  -d : select device" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "  -l : list all platforms and devices" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "  -f : input image file (default: test.ppm)" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "  -h : print this message" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Part 1 - handle command line options such as device selection, verbosity, etc.
    int platform_id = 0;
    int device_id = 0;
    string image_filename = "test.pgm";

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0) && (i < (argc - 1))) { platform_id = atoi(argv[++i]); }
        else if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) && (i < (argc - 1))) { device_id = atoi(argv[++i]); }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-l") == 0) { std::cout << ListPlatformsDevices() << std::endl; }
        else if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) && (i < (argc - 1))) { image_filename = argv[++i]; }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-h") == 0) { print_help(); return 0; }
    }

    cimg::exception_mode(0);

    //detect any potential exceptions
    try {
        CImg<unsigned char> image_input(image_filename.c_str());
        CImgDisplay disp_input(image_input, "input");

        //a 3x3 convolution mask implementing an averaging filter
        std::vector<float> convolution_mask = { 1.f / 9, 1.f / 9, 1.f / 9,
                                                1.f / 9, 1.f / 9, 1.f / 9,
                                                1.f / 9, 1.f / 9, 1.f / 9 };
        std::vector<int> histogram;
        //Part 3 - host operations
        //3.1 Select computing devices
        cl::Context context = GetContext(platform_id, device_id);
        cl::Device device = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0];
        //display the selected device
        std::cout << "Runing on " << GetPlatformName(platform_id) << ", " << GetDeviceName(platform_id, device_id) << std::endl;

        //create a queue to which we will push commands for the device
        cl::CommandQueue queue(context, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);

        //3.2 Load & build the device code
        cl::Program::Sources sources;

        AddSources(sources, "kernels/my_kernels.cl");

        cl::Program program(context, sources);

        //build and debug the kernel code
        try {
            program.build();
        }
        catch (const cl::Error& err) {
            std::cout << "Build Status: " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Build Options:\t" << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS>(context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Build Log:\t " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0]) << std::endl;
            throw err;
        }

        //Part 4 - device operations
        int bins = 256;
        //device - buffers
        cl::Buffer dev_image_input(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, image_input.size());
        cl::Buffer dev_image_output(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, image_input.size()); //should be the same as input image
        cl::Buffer dev_convolution_mask(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, convolution_mask.size() * sizeof(float));
        cl::Buffer dev_histogram(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, bins * sizeof(int));
        //4.1 Copy images to device memory
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(dev_image_input, CL_TRUE, 0, image_input.size(), &image_input.data()[0]);
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(dev_convolution_mask, CL_TRUE, 0, convolution_mask.size() * sizeof(float), &convolution_mask[0]);

        //4.2 Setup and execute the kernel (i.e. device code)
        cl::Kernel kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "identity");
        kernel.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
        kernel.setArg(1, dev_image_output);
        //kernel.setArg(2, dev_convolution_mask);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(image_input.size()), cl::NullRange);

        vector<unsigned char> output_buffer(image_input.size());
        cl::Event imageEvent;
        
        /*
        cl::Kernel kernel_id = cl::Kernel(program, "convolutionND");
        kernel_id.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
        kernel_id.setArg(1, dev_image_output);
        kernel_id.setArg(2, dev_convolution_mask);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_id, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(image_input.width(), image_input.height(), image_input.spectrum()), cl::NullRange, NULL, &imageEvent);
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(dev_image_output, CL_TRUE, 0, output_buffer.size(), &output_buffer.data()[0]);
        */
        cl::Kernel kernel_hist = cl::Kernel(program, "hist_atomic");
        kernel_hist.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
        kernel_hist.setArg(1, dev_histogram);
        kernel_hist.setArg(2, cl::Local(bins * sizeof(int)));
        kernel_hist.setArg(3, bins);
        std::cerr << kernel_hist.getWorkGroupInfo<CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE>(device) << std::endl;
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_hist, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(image_input.size()), bins);
        /*
        cl::Kernel kernel_scan = cl::Kernel(program, "scan_simple");
        kernel_scan.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
        kernel_scan.setArg(1, dev_histogram);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_scan, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(image_input.size()), cl::NullRange);
        */
        cl::Kernel kernel_ble = cl::Kernel(program, "scan_bl");
        kernel_ble.setArg(0, dev_histogram);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_ble, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(bins * sizeof(int)), cl::NullRange);
        
        cl::Kernel kernel_normal = cl::Kernel(program, "normalise");
        kernel_normal.setArg(0, dev_histogram);
        kernel_normal.setArg(1, dev_histogram);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_normal, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(bins * sizeof(int)), cl::NullRange);
        
        cl::Kernel kernel_back = cl::Kernel(program, "back_project");
        kernel_back.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
        kernel_back.setArg(1, dev_image_output);
        kernel_back.setArg(2, dev_histogram);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_back, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(image_input.size()), cl::NullRange);
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(dev_image_output, CL_TRUE, 0, output_buffer.size(), &output_buffer.data()[0]);
        
        CImg<unsigned char> output_image(output_buffer.data(), image_input.width(), image_input.height(), image_input.depth(), image_input.spectrum());
        CImgDisplay disp_output(output_image, "output");
        while (!disp_input.is_closed() && !disp_output.is_closed()
            && !disp_input.is_keyESC() && !disp_output.is_keyESC()) {
            disp_input.wait(1);
            disp_output.wait(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Vector profiling: " <<
            imageEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
            imageEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>() << std::endl;

    }
    catch (const cl::Error& err) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << ", " << getErrorString(err.err()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (CImgException& err) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Kernel code

```
kernel void hist_atomic(global const int* A, global int* H, local int* LH, int nr_bins) 
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    int bin_index = A[id];
    if(lid < nr_bins) 
    {
        LH[lid] = 0;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    //increment function
    atomic_inc(&LH[bin_index]); //assumes bins are set to 0
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    atomic_add(&H[id], LH[id]);
}
kernel void scan_simple(global int* A, global int* B) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int N = get_global_size(0);
    global int* C;

    for (int stride = 1; stride < N; stride *= 2) {
        B[id] = A[id];
        if (id >= stride)
            B[id] += A[id - stride];

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); //sync the step

        C = A; A = B; B = C; //swap A & B between steps
    }
}
kernel void scan_bl(global int* A) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int N = get_global_size(0);
    int t;

    //up-sweep
    for (int stride = 1; stride < N; stride *= 2) {
        if (((id + 1) % (stride*2)) == 0)
            A[id] += A[id - stride];

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); //sync the step
    }

    //down-sweep
    if (id == 0)
        A[N-1] = 0;//exclusive scan

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); //sync the step

    for (int stride = N/2; stride > 0; stride /= 2) {
        if (((id + 1) % (stride*2)) == 0) {
            t = A[id];
            A[id] += A[id - stride]; //reduce 
            A[id - stride] = t;      //move
        }

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); //sync the step
    }
}
kernel void normalise(global int* A, global int* H) 
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int last = A[get_global_size(0) - 1];
    H[id] = (A[id] / last);
    printf("H[id] = %d", H[id]);
}
kernel void back_project(global const int* A, global int* B, global int* H) 
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    B[id] = H[A[id]];
}
```

I believe I have got the kernel functions correct, to normalise I was told to get the last value in the histogram (since this is the max value), though I am getting an error when I try to implement my back_project function which is the out of resources error. I'm not sure if it's because the things that I am passing into the ND::Range function are correct or not. I'm new to this, so I wouldn't mind if anyone knows some potentially reasons this isn't working.

Comment: Where is LH declared?

Comment: The line here "kernel_hist.setArg(2, cl::Local(bins * sizeof(int)));" which should seperate the histogram into seperate work groups, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I don't think that works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249801/passing-arguments-through-local-memory-in-opencl